# Container for properties values

Tags: c#, .net

When .NET 4.5 was released i started using such great Attribute as `CallerMemberName`. It's easier to understand code, developers can write it faster also. It's like a snippet, not only a feature for debug/test purposes.

So I have a question. Is it normal to create and use something like this?

```cs
public class PropertyStore
{
    Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    ViewModelBase modelBase;

    internal PropertyStore(ViewModelBase _base)
    {
        modelBase = _base;
    }

    public void SetValue<T>(T value = default(T), [CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        T prev = GetValue<T>(prop);
        if ((prev == null && value == null) || (prev != null && prev.Equals(value))) return;
        data[prop] = value;
        modelBase.OnPropertyChanged(prop);
    }

    public T GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (!data.ContainsKey(prop))
            data[prop] = default(T);
        return (T)data[prop];
    }
}
```

Class-helper, that makes other class more readable, and also we have list of our properties without need to use Reflection.
The usage is:

```cs
public class SampleClass : ViewModelBase
{
    PropertyStore PropertyStore;

    public SampleClass ()
    {
        PropertyStore = new PropertyStore(this);
    }

    public string Key
    {
        get { return PropertyStore.GetValue<string>(); }
        set { PropertyStore.SetValue(value); }
    }
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return PropertyStore.GetValue<DateTime>(); }
        set { PropertyStore.SetValue(value); }
    }
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return PropertyStore.GetValue<bool>(); }
        set { PropertyStore.SetValue(value); }
    }
}
```

The class `ViewModelBase` here simply implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

As I understand, this approach is something like Microsoft Dependency Properties, but I don't need all power of `DependencyObject` class, and I don't want inherit it.
With something like this I can use Binding, because it's enough to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, also we have no fields (as for me, i try to use properties smarter, than using fields directly (however, there is no problem to use `Dictionary` directly ^_^))

Sorry for my bad English... Not main language and not much practice.

Another Sample (after moving Methods to base class)

```cs
public class SampleClass : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Key
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }
    }
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return GetValue<DateTime>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }
    }
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return GetValue<bool>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }
    }
}
```

No diff with Microsoft's WPF Property System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice idea, property bag without reflection and it will even work with obfuscation.

I don't see major problems with it but you may consider the following:

1. The prop parameter is optional so potentially a bug can be introduced by given a value in the call.
2. Value types will get boxed.
3. Access to the fields is relatively more expensive, can be a factor more expensive as you have much more code in a simple get (especially with boxing).
4. Dictionary takes more space than the number of properties you keep in (especially with boxing).
5. Each property also stores a string of the property name adding to the overhead.

Comment: thx for the answer. Nothing can do with optional... so my team  must be careful. Yes, but even Microsoft used special class to boxing boolean :) 3 and 4 a big minus of such approach, yes. In perspective it can be not only Name, but also another "metadata". As for me, it's very usefull because, as you said, it's "bag without reflection". Need much doing dynamically...

Answer (score 2):

Only feature you'll get with it is an ability to access property values via Dictionary.Get|Set methods.

You can get this ability with field based implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged. You can access property values by its name using dictionary, with property name to precompiled delegate mapping like it done in [Yappi](http://yappi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17477#86395) project.

```
var dateValue= Property<SampleClass>.Get<DateTime>(this,"Date");
Property<SampleClass>.Set<DateTime>(this,"Date",DateTime.Now);
```

Both can be rewritten as extension methods.

Comment: Well, it's runtime realisation...out of competition ^_^ I'll think about. Thx for the link.

Comment: Advantage of this that you can use this with any existing class with minimal changes. Whereas original idea require you to change all the get and set accessors to the same repetitive code.